# '+' gets stored as '%2b' in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

the + sign gets encoded as %2b while storing it from textbox in database. i want to store it as + only. So how to achieve that? thanks for the help.

Comment: I doubt it. You are probably passing in `%2b` to the database. Where did you get the value from? It looks like a URL encoded `+`.

Comment: got it from asp.net textbox. i try to store number +43434

Comment: There you go - I am assuming your form uses `method="POST"`. The value gets URL encoded in the process. You need to URL decode it before sending to the database, as most answers here show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value is being URL encoded. To decode, try:

```
var decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(input);
```

Comment: Or better, find out why it's encoded in the first place?  The TextBox control normally takes care of decoding.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Server.HtmlDecode(Textbox.Text)
```

to save.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
string value = Server.HtmlDecode(TextBox1.Text);
```